# How to cast to your Model object at reading from Mongo instead reading DBObject?

Tags: java, mongodb, crud

I wondering to know how to read saced object from MongoDB.

I just saved it with key (dataStatus) and object was converted to JSON.

When I tryng to retrieve it - I have DBObject instead of my model.

easy ***main()***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      
        LowFareSearchRQDao searchRQDao = new LowFareSearchRQDao();
        searchRQDao.connect();
        System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(searchRQDao.read(DataStatus.SUCCESS_LOW_FARE_SEARCH_REQUEST), ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
        searchRQDao.disconnect();
    }
```

Output:

```
com.mongodb.BasicDBObject@76e134e6[
  _isPartialObject=false
  accessOrder=false
  threshold=12
  loadFactor=0.75
]
```

Here is my create():

```
@Override
public void create(MODEL model) {
    try {
        Field keyField1 = getKeyField(model);
        String fieldValue = getKeyFieldValue(keyField1, model);
        BasicDBObject query = createQuery(keyField1.getName(), fieldValue);

        DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
        if (!cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject dbObject = getDbObject(model);
            dbCollection.insert(dbObject);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Duplicate data status %s with value %s", keyField1.getName(), fieldValue));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Field getKeyField(MODEL model) {
    Field keyField = null;
    for (Field field : model.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(KeyField.class)) {
            keyField = field;
        }
    }
    if (keyField == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Couldn't find KeyField annotation at class '%s'", model.getClass().getName()));
    }
    return keyField;
}

private String getKeyFieldValue(Field keyField, Object model) {
    String result = null;
    try {
        if(keyField.isAnnotationPresent(KeyField.class)) {
            keyField.setAccessible(true);
            result = keyField.get(model).toString();
        }
        if(result == null || result.equals("")) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("KeyField property is empty");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Couldn't find KeyField annotation at class '%s'", model.getClass().getName()));
    }
    return result;
}

private BasicDBObject createQuery(String key, String value) {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put(key, value);
    return query;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MODEL read(ID id) {
    Field keyField2 = getKeyField(model);
    BasicDBObject query = createQuery(keyField2.getName(), id.toString());

    DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
    if (!cursor.hasNext()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("This id %s isn't presented at collection %s", id.toString(), dbCollection.getFullName()));
    }
    return (MODEL) JSON.parse(String.valueOf(cursor.next()));
}
```

***How to convert from DBObject to your model object?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

For this purpose I used ObjectMapper. And I want to skip when my objet contains unknown properties as `_id`.

Here is code snippet:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MODEL read(ID id) {
        Field keyField2 = getKeyField(model);
        BasicDBObject query = createQuery(keyField2.getName(), id.toString());

        DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
        if (!cursor.hasNext()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("This id %s isn't presented at collection %s", id.toString(), dbCollection.getFullName()));
        }
        String json = cursor.next().toString();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        MODEL value   = null;
        try {
            value = mapper.readValue(json, model);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> *How to convert from DBObject to your model object?*

This is one way where you can achieve it in a simplified manner:

Make your class `extend` `BasicDBObject`, with a parameterized constructor.

```
class Model extends BasicDBObject
{
   public Model(DBObject object) {
        super(object.toMap());
   }
}
```

Setting values in a Model.

```
Model model = new Model();
model.put("key","value");
```

Inserting a Model into the database.

```
dbCollection.insert(model);
```

Retrieving a Model from the database.

```
while(cursor.hasNext()){
 DbObject obj = cursor.next();
 Model model = new Model(obj);
 //do something with the Model
 }
```

Comment: What i suggested is the standard way of storing and retrieving from the mongo database as suggested in the docs. Anyway you can use whatever suits your app design.